# Failed to save: Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Sudo' to retry as superuser. M1 Mac

Tags: macos, github, visual-studio-code, permissions, apple-m1

I just cloned a GitHub repository on my M1 mac and opened the folder with VsCode but when I make changes in the file and try to save it, I get the error **Failed to save 'Home.js': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Sudo' to retry as superuser.**

What might be the solution?

Comment: Look at the files from terminal (e.g. `ls -l`). That will tell you who the owner and the group are and what the permissions are. You can use `chmod` to give yourself write permissions. Don’t mess with the executable bit, only the write bit.

Comment: If you do a web search for `ls chmod`, you’ll see tons of links that introduce you to these two commands.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to change your permissions for this file.

You can see the permissions for this file running the command:

```
ls -@l file
```

To change the permissions you can run

```
sudo chown -v username directory
```

If you want to change permissions on a whole directory run:

```
sudo chown -Rv username directory
```

Answer (score 3):

If there's anyone out there who doesn't understand this;

Just click>get Info> sharing & permissions> and make sure all privileges are set to "Read & Write"

Then click on the small three dots at the bottom and click on "Apply to..."
[image]

Comment: To the folder you're working in> Get info.....